# How do I start a screen session in a Python method and leave it running forever?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to write a Python method that starts up a Screen session, starts a script in that session, and then leaves the Screen session running forever after the script or IPython session that called the method exits.

Currently, the code looks something like this:

```
def [name of the method]:
   proc = subprocess.Popen(['screen -S [the name I want to give to the session]'],
                           cwd=[the place where I want to run this],
                           shell=True,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS)
   proc.stdin.write([the command to start up that other script])
   return
```

This does not work. As far as I can tell, the Screen session simply shuts down when the method returns. How do I get it to keep going?

Comment: 'screen', '-dm', '-S', session_name,  # -dm to detach and run in the background

Comment: That doesn't work, unfortunately. It still shuts down.

Comment: wrap it in a [thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) with deamon flag?

Comment: I got Oyinlade's suggestion to work. It works if you use "screen -S [session name] -X stuff '[commands to start things up in the screen session]'". I'll write down a more detailed solution below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ouinlade Demola's suggestion in the comments works. The solution I ended up with looks something like this:

```
def [name of the method]:
    os.system("screen -d -m -S [name of Screen session]")
    os.system("screen -S [name of Screen session] -X stuff 'cd [the place where the script is]'")
    os.system("screen -S [name of Screen session] -X stuff './[name of the script]\n'")
    return
```

ps. Note that 'stuff' is not a placeholder but the name of an actual command to screen. This initially confused me while googling around.

Comment: Good point about `stuff`. It basically pastes the subsequent text into the input buffer of the current window.